# Regular Expression quantifier is matching shorter sequence

Tags: javascript, regex

I am testing a simplified regular expression for identifying possible credit card numbers so we can filter them out. I'm looking for 13-16 digits, optionally with an arbitrary number of spaces and '-'s after each digit, and the whole sequence surrounded by word boundaries.

It seems like this regular expression ought to do the trick (option 1):
`\b(?:\d[ -]*?){13,16}\b`

But when I test this (both in my code (which is in JavaScript) and on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/4CffKF/2)) using a test string of
`1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6` it matches only `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3`, i.e. the shortest number in my `{13,16}` quantifier. Everything I'm reading suggests it ought to match the longest possible sequence, but clearly it isn't.

If I change the regular expression to `\b(?:\d[ -]*?){16}\b` it matches all 16 digits (but of course doesn't match 13-15-digit numbers).

I can work around this using alternation with the longest sequence first, like so (option 2):

```
\b(?:\d[ -]*?){16}|(?:\d[ -]*?){15}|(?:\d[ -]*?){14}|(?:\d[ -]*?){13}\b
```

Or it works if I explicitly add another group to the end after first matching {12,15}, like so (option 3):

```
\b(?:\d[ -]*?){12,15}(?:\d[ -]*?)\b
```

If one of those is the only way to do it, I can live with it, but they're both uglier than the more compact option 1, and I'd also like to understand why option 1 isn't working the way I thought it would. For that matter, why does option 3 seem to behave differently in terms of the number of items it matches? It matches 15 digits instead of 12.

Comment: You're basically seeing the defined behavior of the non-greedy quantifier.

Comment: Remove the `?`: `\b(?:\d[ -]*){13,16}\b`

Comment: In fact you don't really need the `*` at all; it's redundant given the `{13,16}` quantifier.

Comment: @Pointy: The `*` is mandatory, because it any number of  spaces or hyphens may be between each digit.

Comment: OK, I tested and can verify that removing the '?' does make it work, so I appreciate that. But why is the '?' affecting the {13, 15}, which seems like it ought to be a separate quantifier? And why does `\b(?:\d[ -]*?){12,15}(?:\d[ -]*?)\b` work successfully?

Comment: @jwismar `?` is the lazy quantifier, meaning it will match as few characters as possible. 13 in your case, because that's the minimum number of characters that you allowed to match.

Comment: In your case, it maches few characters possible(i.e. 13) before a word boundary

Comment: I understand that `?` in `[ -]*?` would make the `*` match as few of `[ -]` as possible, but it's within a group. It shouldn't affect the {13,16} repetitions of the group, should it?

Comment: @Toto `/\b[\d -]{13,16}\b/`

Comment: It matches 12 (digit+space) when comes the 13th match, it matches the 13th digit then (because the space is optional) it matches the word boundary then stop.

Comment: @jwismar think of the lazy quantifier as iterating up, and trying again if something "outside" it causes the match to fail. As soon as it hits 13, the `{13,16}` quantifier *won't* fail, so it's done.

Comment: @Pointy: This is matching `1 - - - - - -2`

Comment: @Pointy I'm trying to match `[0-9]{13,16}` but also allow `[ -]*` after each one.

Comment: @Toto ah good point, still I think a shorter expression might be possible (a careful statement which is definitely true :) )

Comment: @Toto OK, assuming I accept all this as true, why does \b(?:\d[ -]*?){12,15}(?:\d[ -]*?)\b match all 16 characters? (And thanks for your patience. I want to really get this.)

Comment: `/\b(?:\d[ -]*){13,16}\b/` maybe — if you just want to allow a single space or dash change that `*` to `?` of course

Comment: @jwismar: because the word boundary is **after** the second group.

Comment: @toto but this matches all 16, too: `\b(?:\d[ -]*){12,15}\b(?:\d[ -]*)\b` (Which is nonsensical given my actual requirements, but I'm still trying to understand the expected behaviors.)

Comment: @jwismar: In the second case, the word boundary between the two group is matched between a non-word character (a space) and a word character (a digit). In the original case, there is nothing after the last digit, if you add somthing after the last digit, you will not match the 16 digits, [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/4CffKF/4). Sorry for my poor explanation but English is not my native language and I have some difficulties to explain more clearly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove the lazy quantifier:

```
\b(?:\d[ -]*){13,16}\b
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/4CffKF/3)

Comment: This fixes my immediate problem. Lots of interesting comments and discussion under the original question talking about how the non-greedy `?` is affecting the group repetition quantifier `{13,16}`.

Answer (score 0):

According to this document https://www.regular-expressions.info/creditcard.html

> \b(?:\d[ -]*?){13,16}\b

this is the only way to find card numbers with spaces or dashes in them
all what you need is to remove the lazy "*?" Quantifier

to be like this

> \b(?:\d[ -]*){13,16}\b